# Return all rows that are considered outliers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, boxplot

My `df` has this structure -

```
id  client     Calls
153 2409        1.0
154 2410        2.0
155 2690        2.0
156 2210        3.0
157 2460        41.0
```

I am using the following piece of code to calculate outliers -

```
outliers = [y for stat in boxplot_stats(df['Calls']) for y in stat['fliers']]
```

The output of that is

```
id     calls
1      41.0
```

How do I get it to return the actual row from `df`. For example -

```
    id  client      calls
    157 2460        41.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we do not know what is `stat`, I can only base on your `outliers` get what you need using `isin`

```
yourdf=df[df.Calls.isin(outliers.calls)]
```